# How do I get the real error message in HttpClient response.ReasonPhrase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

### My Setting

I have 2 WebApi projects with the following flow:

1. **User** makes request to **API 1**
2. **API 1** makes request to **API 2** on behalf of the user (using an `HttpClient`).

---

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.SetBearerToken(token);

    string endpoint = PbbSettings.Identity.Users.Delete.Replace("{userId}", userId);

    // Attempt deletion of the user
    using (var response = await client.DeleteAsync(endpoint))
    {
        // Throw exception if not succeeded
        EnsureSuccess(response);
    }
}
```

### The Problem

So the flow of control and information works fine.
The problem is that when **API 2** responds with an error, `response.ReasonPhrase` says "Bad Request" or "Internal Server Error", instead of the message I set in the exception.

Been spitting blood on this for a whole day now. Any insights?

### More Info (TLDR)

For clarity, all my APIs have a global exception filter registered to handle errors:

```
public class RepositoryExceptionsHandlerAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        HandleException(context);

        base.OnException(context);
    }

    public override Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HandleException(context);

        return base.OnExceptionAsync(context, cancellationToken);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recognizes common repository exceptions and if necessary creates a response and updates the context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context in which the exception was thrown.</param>
    private void HandleException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var response = CreateResponse(context.Request, context.Exception);

        if (response != null)
            context.Response = response;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recognizes common repository exceptions and creates a corresponding error response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request to which the response should be created.</param>
    /// <param name="ex">The exception to handle.</param>
    /// <returns>An error response containing the status code and exception data, or null if this is not a common exception.</returns>
    private HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, Exception ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message;

        if (ex is KeyNotFoundException)        return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        if (ex is ArgumentException)           return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message);
        if (ex is InvalidOperationException)   return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message);
        if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException) return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, message);
#if !DEBUG
        // For security reasons, when an exception is not handled the system should return a general error, not exposing the real error information
        // In development time, the programmer will need the details of the error, so this general message is disabled.
        request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Errors.InternalServerError);
#endif

        return null;
    }
}
```

This works fine between the **user** and **API 1**.
But when **API 1** and **API 2** do their thing, the response creation ignores the message I put in and sets the status as the reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new CreateResponse() method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Recognizes common repository exceptions and creates a corresponding error response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The request to which the response should be created.</param>
    /// <param name="ex">The exception to handle.</param>
    /// <returns>An error response containing the status code and exception data, or null if this is not a common exception.</returns>
    private HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, Exception ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message;

        HttpStatusCode code = 0;

        if      (ex is KeyNotFoundException)        code = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        else if (ex is ArgumentException)           code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        else if (ex is InvalidOperationException)   code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        else if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException) code = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        else if (ex is HttpException)
        {
            // HttpExceptions are thrown when request between IdentityServer and the API server have failed.
            // IdentityServer has generated an error, the API server received it and now it needs to relay it back to the client.
            var httpException = (HttpException) ex;

            code = (HttpStatusCode) httpException.GetHttpCode();
            message = httpException.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

            // For security reasons, when an exception is not handled the system should return a general error, not exposing the real error information
            // In development time, the programmer will need the details of the error, so this general message is disabled.
#if DEBUG
            message = ex.Message;
#else
            message = Errors.InternalServerError;
#endif
        }

        // For some reason the request.CreateErrorResponse() method ignores the message given to it and parses its own message.
        // The error response is constructed manually.
        return CreateErrorResponse(request, code, message);
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage CreateErrorResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode code, string message)
    {
        var content = new { Message = message };

        return new HttpResponseMessage(code)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = message,
            RequestMessage = request,
            Content = new ObjectContent(content.GetType(), content, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
        };
    }
}
```

Hope this just saved someone's day... ;)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way it to use await reponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() if the API returns error messages as plain text. But that depends on the API you are calling. If the API at hand uses some custom JSON or XML format you can try to first parse the response content and interpret it. But be aware that parsing JSON / XML /  might cause secondary exceptions. Those should be caught and then simply display the original content as string or some general error message that an error occurred, but more detailed information is not available. One should also check if the messages from the underlying API are useful to users and do not leak information.